# How can I reject user registration with certain username in default laravel register form?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to block users from using certain names like 'admin' or 'operator'.

I've tried fiddling with both **Controllers/Auth/RegisterController** and **Controller/RegisterController** but failed.

What I've tried was something like this:

```
in Controllers/Auth/RegisterController,


if ($data['name'] === 'admin' || $data['name'] === 'operator') {
             return redirect()->back()->withErrors(['Invalid username']);
        } 
else {
    session()->flash('message', 'Welcome!');

    return User::create([
    'name' => $data['name'],
    'email' => $data['email'],
    'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
            ]);
        }
```

The code above gave me this error:

> Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::login() must be an
>   instance of Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, string given,
>   called in /var/www/vendor/laravel/ui/auth-backend/RegistersUsers.php
>   on line 36

I've also searched whether validators can block specific words but failed.
I know I can work this around by using JS, but I think Laravel would have some function like this.

Comment: In my opinion this has to be done in your registration model, with custom `rule` make a function which will detect predefined names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Go to RegisterController.php.

   2. There will be a validator(array $data) function that validates your registration input.
   3. Add not_in validation check for the name field.

Something like this:

```
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255', 'not_in:admin,operator'],
            'pan' => ['required', 'string', 'min:10', 'max:10', 'unique:users,username'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
        ]);
    }
```

Hopefully, this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to validate if requested name is not in the list of predefined blocked names:

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

Validator::make($data, [
    'toppings' => [
        'required',
        Rule::notIn(['admin', 'superuser']),//etc..
    ],
]);
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I did in Laravel 9 with the Breeze scaffolding.

I created a separate "Services" trait with the reserved usernames, so that I can easily implement and extend it.

1. Create a `Services` folder at `app/Services`
2. Create a trait `Reserved` at `app/Services/Reserved.php`

##### Reserved.php

```php
<?php

namespace App\Services;

trait Reserved
{
    public static function usernames()
    {
        return ['admin', 'operator', 'someBadWord'];
    }
}
```

3. Next open `app/Http/Controllers/Auth/RegisteredUserController.php` and import the trait, then add it.
4. Now just add it to your validation rules using the `notIn` rule.

```
Rule::notIn(Reserved::usernames())
```

##### RegisteredUserController.php

```php
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;
use App\Services\Reserved;

class RegisteredUserController extends Controller
{
    use Reserved;
    ...

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'username' => ['required', 'string', 'max:16', 'unique:users', Rule::notIn(Reserved::usernames())],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'confirmed', Rules\Password::defaults()],
        ]);

        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create RegisterControllerRequest using the following command:

```
php artisan make:request RegisterControllerRequest
```

find out your recent created file in `app/Http/Requests`, then update `rules()` to be:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name' => 'required|notIn:admin,operator',
    ];
}
```

Then update your controller to use the new validation:

After name space add:

```
use  App\Http\Requests\RegisterControllerRequest;
```

And finally inject the validation as a parameter in your register method:

```
public function register (RegisterControllerRequest $request)
```

For more information check documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#form-request-validation